# How to interact with redux through a Detox test?

Tags: detox

I am using Detox to test a react-native app I have. Part of the app flow involves logging in in order to access certain parts of the app. I would like to test specific aspects of the app past the login screen, but I don't want to have to login in each time that the test runs as that introduces additional complexity and is not actually the tradditional user flow (users would typically stay logged in after they initially logged in to the app).

I am trying to find a way to set the redux state before launching the app, or some way to specifically mock the state of the app after opening it.

I looked through the docs on Mocking, but it did not seem like there was anything about directly interacting with redux

I tried launching the app as a new instance, then calling the redux store to set the state that a logged in user would have, and then reloading the app, but this did not result in the user logged in